# zpool online doesn't work

Tags: solaris, zfs

I've hard disk failure on this pool. I replace the disk, I don't have any hard error and I can not to put back it online as nofified:

```
:~# zpool status data
  pool: data
 state: UNAVAIL
status: One or more devices could not be opened.  There are insufficient
        replicas for the pool to continue functioning.
action: Attach the missing device and online it using 'zpool online'.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-3C
 scan: none requested
config:

NAME                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
data                    UNAVAIL      0     0     0  insufficient replicas
  raidz2-0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    c2t2d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    c2t3d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    c2t4d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    c2t15d0             ONLINE       0     0     0
    c2t6d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    c2t7d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    c2t8d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    c2t9d0              ONLINE       0     0     0
    c2t10d0             ONLINE       0     0     0
  14132293493917319721  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/dsk/c2t11d0s0
  c2t12d0               ONLINE       0     0     0
  c2t13d0               ONLINE       0     0     0
  c2t14d0               ONLINE       0     0     0
```

I tried this command:

```
:~# zpool online -e  data  c2t5d0 
cannot open 'data': pool is unavailable
```

Why the zpool data still unavailable?

c2t0d0 and c2t1d0 are reserved for the system and are in z mirror.
unavailable

And I would like to know what 's meaning this line:

```
14132293493917319721  UNAVAIL      0     0     0  was /dev/dsk/c2t11d0s0
```

because in my mind there's should be like this:

```
c2t11d0        UNAVAIL     0  0   0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thks Marco, I used `:~# zpool replace data  c2t5d0` and I got this `cannot open 'data': pool is unavailable`

Comment: I believe you need to first remove it from the pool in order to replace it.

Comment: You have a severe problem: four of your disks (c2t11 through c2t14) are toplevel "stripe" disks. The loss of one disk means the loss of the entire pool, despite the fact that you've got a 9-way raidz2 in there. If you ever do recover your c2t11 disk, I highly recommend backing up the pool, recreating it from scratch with proper redundancy, and then restoring.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to remove from the pool prior to replacing. See the docs for a better explanation then I can provide: [Replacing a Device in a ZFS Storage Pool | Oracle Help Center](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19253-01/819-5461/6n7ht6r7p/index.html)

Comment: c2t11d0 is a toplevel - it can't be removed, only replaced. The original disk needs to be found (or have the connector re-seated) before it can be replaced, because zfs needs something to copy the data from.

Comment: I backup the data of  pool  and I restored it after replacing the damaged disk. I put 3 disks in the spare